# Publishing list content

Tags: list

How to show the publishing list content in a page with like and comment and unlike button in SharePoint. I have a SharePoint list with workflow. Once it is published, it has to show in the SharePoint page with like, unlike and comment options to display and also to count the like and unlike.

Comment: Provide more information please, SharePoint On-Prem/Online? Are these only text records?

Comment: SharePoint On premise. Yes only text record. User need to submit the form once review by approver and it has to published in a page. In a page it will show like like, unlike and comments.

Comment: Version of SharePoint?

Comment: sharepoint 2016